# Node.js client library batch requests to Gmail API

Tags: node.js, google-api, gmail-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I have an Node.js app which retrieves e-mail threads for a large number of users (200.000+). I am using the `Node.js client library`.

I authenticate each user separately using JWT and a Service account with domain wide delegation on the users' side, then call the `threads.list` endpoint as follows:

```
const { google } = require('googleapis');

const jwt = new google.auth.JWT(
  SERVICE_ACCOUNT.client_email,
  null,
  SERVICE_ACCOUNT.private_key,
  ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'],
  user,
);

const auth = await authorize(jwt);
const gmail = google.gmail({ version: 'v1', auth });
const response = await gmail.users.threads.list({ userId: user, maxResults: 50 })
```

Considering the large number of users, I've been thinking about implementing batch requests to group more users per request instead of going one by one, but I'm unable to find information on how to do that using the `Node.js client library`. Also, considering that each user has to be authorized for me to be able to retrieve their data, how would I handle that in a batch request ?

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: all batching will save you is the HTTP call, its not going to help with your quota usage and as far as i remember there is a max of 5 requests per batch and they all have to be the same request type

Comment: Quota is not an issue here, I'm simply trying to see what can be done to make this process as optimal and fast as possible. Right now there are multiple API calls per user to list all threads and to get each of those threads.

Comment: If you want to make the process optional and fast then i wouldn't bother trying to figure out batching its not documented and in my preference doesn't work very well

Comment: That being said i did a quick scan of the https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client library and i cant see anything that tells me that they have even enabled batching but you could of course code it yourself https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/batch

Comment: Take a look at the [batch request guide](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/batch) and let me know if implementing that following this guide did optimise your functionality or if you need more help defining this call.

Comment: Already looked at that guide, but the problem there is that apparently you only put one authorization header in the main http request for all batched requests. To read e-mails with the Gmail API, I need to authorize each separate user.

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

There is no way of batching a request of **listing the threads of multiple users** as that would require authorization for each one of them and they are separate entities.

## Workaround

You could try to make an `Array` of `userIds` or of `jwts` and then iterate the process in a `for` loop going through each element of the array, authorising it and storing the thread list into an `Array`.

I hope this has helped you. Let me know if you need anything else or if you did not understood something. :)